# pywinauto and Windows Media Encoder

Tags: pywinauto

I'm trying to control windows media encoder to switch sources. The source control in wme is called a 'Pane' When I run PrintControlIdentifiers I see the Sources pane coordinates
and I can call the clickInput() function on it to select Source1 or Source2 but this is 
problematic because they are not always in the foreground. I tried using Click(coords = (x,y) in the same manner as ClickInput() but it does not work. And I cannot seem to get pywinauto to give me any information about the Source1 and Source2 objects.

Here's a jpeg of the encoder window for reference:  http://web.ncf.ca/fj385/wme.JPG

Can anyone help me change the sources on this stream without using ClickInput()?
thanks
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to switch sources on the Sources panel.

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Untitled - Windows Media Encoder', class_name='MS Windows Media Encoder')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
ctrl = window['Toolbar']  # Sources Toolbar
ctrl.Button(0).Click()  # Select Source1
ctrl.Button(1).Click()  # Select Source2
```

Code generated with [SWAPY](http://code.google.com/p/swapy/)

I am the author of this utility.

Comment: Nic job on the GUI, I'm trying to use it to recreate the code you posted here. By using set focus Swapy writes the first three lines plus a window.setFocus(). Is that the way you instantiated the ctrl variable? by using setFocus?

Comment: Yes, I did it twice - on window and on the control(Source1). But it neens only for SWAPY generate a working code.